# What is the difference between $.get and $.getJSON?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I am trying to figure out the difference between $.get and $.getJSON

I have an external file that is called Test.JSON and it contains just the following:

```
{ "name": "John" }
```

I can use

```
$.getJSON('Test.JSON', function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

or this

```
$.get('Test.JSON', function(data) {
  console.log(data);
});
```

And I get the **same result** in the console,

```
Object {name: "getJSON"}
```

Is it because my file extension is .JSON?

If I change the file extension to .js (ie Test.js) then nothing is printed to the console for the $.get, but I still get the same result for the $.getJSON

As a second part to this question, I thought that if I enclosed the object in Test.js in single quotes

```
'{ "name": "John" }'
```

then I could do this:

```
$.get('Test.js', function(data) {
  console.log($.parseJSON(data));
});
```

But this gives me

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token '
```

As you can see, I am totally confused.

Answer (score 2):

In case `$.getJSON`

- jQuery sends an `Accept: application/json` header
- jQuery interprets the inbound response, converts it into a JavaScript Object, and passes it into the callback (so you don't have to mess with eval or other conversion mechanism).

A number of server-side frameworks (such as Rails) automatically detect the `Accept` header and handle the request appropriately. If you are using a different framework or rolling your own, you can inspect the `Accept` header to detect the format .

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting the Syntax error, is because the input is this:

```
"'{ \"name\": \"John\" }'"
```

`$.parseJSON` should work just fine without the extra single quotes. Are you sure you didn't have typos the first time you've tried?

Comment: No typo.  I have added to my own question with some more clarifation.  I am quite puzzled by this.

Answer (score 0):

I removed the single quote so Test.js is just

```
{ "name": "John" }
```

When I try

```
$.get('Test.js', function(data) {
  console.log($parseJSON(data));
});
```

Nothing appears in the console at all.

If I do this

```
var data = '{"name":"John"}'
console.log($.parseJSON(data));
```

Then I get the desired result of course.

I am just struggling with trying to understand why when I use $.get to retrieve that string (with or without the single quote surrounding the object), I either get an error, or no object at all.

Comment: I just figured it out.  I need to add the **html** datatype to the $.get function